# Notepad++ auto-complete double quotes

Tags: notepad++, double-quotes

First to say I have Settings > Preferences > Auto completion > Auto-insert everything enabled.

But when I am writting HTML code and type something like `<div class="|` (where | is cursor position) it wont add the ending double quotes. But with  [ { ( it works fine. For auto-completion of double quotes to work for me, there have to be blank space before and after them (so something like this works `<div class= "|"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you choose `"` in two fields start and end :[image]

Comment: thank you, one would thought the checkbox near the double qoutes will be enough :)